# Spring Hibernate mapping with Embedded ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a following relationships:

```
FirstEntity {
    List<SecondEntity> secondEntities;
}

SecondEntity{
    @EmbeddedId
    EmbeddedIdEntity embedded;
    List<ThirdEntity> thirdEntities;
}

@Embeddable
EmbeddedIdEntity {
    long firstEntityId;
    String someValue;
}
```

Now I'm struggling how do I map all these entities so that when I do

```
FirstEntity firstEntity = new FirstEntity();
firstEntity.setSecondEntities(secondEntities);
firstEntityRepository.save(firstEntity);
```

FirstEntity saves, and SecondEntity table is populated with id of FirstEntity

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use the counterpart to `@OneToMany`:

```
FirstEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // Cascades persisting of FirstEntity to secondEntities
    List<SecondEntity> secondEntities;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
EmbeddedIdEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    FirstEntity firstEntity;
    String someValue;
}
```

and save them using something similar to

```
FirstEntity firstEntity = new FirstEntity();
firstEntity.setSecondEntities(secondEntities);
firstEntityRepository.save(firstEntity);
firstEntity.getSecondEntities().forEach(secondEntity -> secondEntity.getEmbedded().setFirstEntity(firstEntity); // Set the counter-relationship on the managed entities
```